# php foreach supplied argument not valid

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, foreach

I am getting results from a mysql table and putting each cell into an array as follows:

```
$sqlArray = mysql_query("SELECT id,firstName FROM members WHERE id='$id'");
while ($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlArray)) {
    $friendArray[] = array(
    'id' => $arrayRow['id'],
    'firstName' => $arrayRow['firstName'],
    );          
}
```

Then I do a search for a specific friend. For example if I want to search for a friend name *Osman*, i would type and `o` and it will return to me all the results that start with the letter `o`. Here is my code for that:

```
function array_multi_search($array, $index, $pattern, $invert = FALSE) {
    $output = array();
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach($array as $i => $arr) {
            // The index must exist and match the pattern
            if (isset($arr[$index]) && (bool) $invert !== (bool) preg_match($pattern, $arr[$index])) {
                $output[$i] = $arr;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
$filtered = array_multi_search($friendArray, 'firstName', '/^o/i');
```

and then it will print out all the results. My problem is that it returned an error saying `"Invalid argument supplied to foreach()"` and that is why I added the `if(is_array))` condition. It is working fine if I leave this code in the `index.php` page, but I moved it to a subfolder named `phpScripts` and it doesn't work there. Any Help?

`$output` is not returning any value because apparently `$friendArray` is not an array. But I verified that it is by using `print_r($friendArray)` and it returns all the member's `id` and `firstName`.

P.S. I use JavaScript to the the call using AJAX.

Comment: I think your $array is null, can you print_r($array); ??
 foreach(null as $element)
is going to fail bigtime.

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied to foreach()` is pretty clear

Comment: I thought that as well but print_r($friendArray) returns me the member's id and firstName

Comment: so the array is not null

Comment: does $friendArray become $array? which is them used in the foreach?

Comment: can you pass in $friendArray[0] instead of $friendArray ?? and let me know if that helped?

or post the result of print_r($array); just above the if statement.

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala it still doesnt work

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala what do you mean by hard coded?

Comment: ok do one thing, test it by sending a hard coded value for array. something like $filtered = array_multi_search(array('id'=>'433434','firstName'=>'foobar'), 'firstName', '/^o/i'); Also pleas epost the contents of $array(result of print_r)

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala ok I tried that and it does return a value, but not what I expected

Comment: ok now print_r($array) and compare the result with array('id'=>'433434','firstName'=>'foobar'), any different?

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala yes they are... print_r($array) returns 1 and array_multi_search(array('id'=>'1341','firstName'=>'marifer'), 'firstName', '/^o/i');  returns m

Answer (score 0):

If your array structure is such:

```
$friendArray[] = array(
    'id' => $arrayRow['id'],
    'firstName' => $arrayRow['firstName'],
);
```

This means your array is indexed and two levels.

So the correct way to walk through it is:

```
foreach($array as $cur_element) {
    $id = $cur_element['id'];
    $firstName = $cur_element['firstName'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
foreach($array as $i => $arr) {
```

To this:

```
foreach((array)$array as $i => $arr) {
```

Are you sure that `$array` is **not** empty?